# Как передать значения переменных от одного класса другому C#

Tags: c#

Проблема в том что я должен в методе одного из классов получить значения переменных(результат выполнения) одного из методов другого класса, как это реализовать, какие существуют способы?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает вызов того метода и получение возвращаемого значения?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Что значит "как это реализовать"? Изучить язык в минимальном объеме, вот как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public class OdinKlass
  {
    public void MetodOdnogoKlassa()
    {
      int local1;
      double local2;
      DrugojKlass drugoj = new DrugojKlass();
      if (drugoj.MetodDrugogoKlassa(out local1, out local2))
      {
        // Ura, zarabotalo!
      }
    }
  }

  public class DrugojKlass
  {
    public bool MetodDrugogoKlassa(out int peremennaja1, out double peremennaja2)
    {
      peremennaja1 = 1;
      peremennaja2 = 2.3;

      return true;
    }
  }
```